# How to symmetrize the armature?

Tags: armature

[image]

I want to copy the bones on one side symmetrically.

I selected the bone to be symmetrized and armature-> symmetrize, but nothing happened.

How can I symmetrize the bones?

Answer (score 1):

1. Select the bones and change pivot point as 3DCursor which on the origin point
2. Scale bones on X-Axis and type "-1" as value

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cGvalWG8HBU&t=428s
Also this tutoriol will helps you for more information about armature and bones.

Comment: Thank you. I thought that I could do the same with armature->symmetrize, but I can not do it.

Comment: With this method, I found that the copied bone was not connected to the backbone, and when I rotated to pose it fell away from the original bones.
How can I connect copied bones to the original bones?