# "Symmetrize armature" flips bones vertically

Tags: armature

When I try to copy my dragon's bones to the right side using Symmetrize, they are flipped vertically instead.
Before:

[image: before]

After:

[image: after]

I have done my homework. The model is oriented correctly, and the naming convention is followed rigorously. I have tried a lot of solutions ([1](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/140615/armature-symmetrizing-problems), [2](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/179965/armature-symmetrize-wrong-position) (for some reason I cannot set the origin of the armature), [3](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/96127/how-to-symmetrize-the-armature), [4](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/215197/symmetrized-armature-keeps-appearing-on-the-same-side-as-the-armature-that-i-wan), [5](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/186602/cant-symmetrize-amatures-correctly), [6](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/115184/symmetrize-bones-not-working-as-expected), [7](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/194148/symmetrize-option-doesnt-mirror-bones-on-the-axis)). No salvation.

Blender version is 2.92.0.

Please let me know what I can do to symmetrise my dragon's skeleton :D

Here's the file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1B3t23a3seoDxLt-gBZjEaaveng0zwQk3/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

**It turned out that I had an unapplied rotation to the mesh.** For reference for anyone with a similar problem: go to object mode, select everything, ctrl+A, apply everything. Then make sure any of your mirror effects still work because now the axis may have changed. Symmetrize works now.